# Best way to store in a structure the args and kwargs for a function/method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Best way to keep args and kwargs for a function/method.

I have a function that I need to call with multiple set of arguments, args and kwargs.

```
t.addelement("tas", "alpha", action="pro", set=False)
t.addelement("mas", "beta", action="sub", set=False)
t.addelement("mas", "beta", action="sub", set=True)
```

I want to keep the arguments outside, like in a list and do a loop:

```
 for args in args_list:
   t.addelement(args)
```

What is the best way, structure to store the arguments ?

Comment: "best" in what sense?

Comment: "best" also depends heavily on how you create those arguments. Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the signature of the function, you could use [inspect.BoundArguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments). Other than that, I'm not aware of any builtin Python structure for this.

You can do something simple, similar to what others suggested:

```py
args = (["foo"], {"baz":"baz"}) # (args, kwargs) tuple
# ...and call something with it
test(*args[0], **args[1])
```

However, I've come across the need a couple times and find the following to be much cleaner:

```py
class Arguments:
    """ Container for args and kwargs """
    __slots__ = ["args","kwargs"]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Call something with these arguments, returning the result;
            you can pass additional arguments which will be injected after the arguments
            passed to the constructor (mimicking functools.partial behavior)
        """
        return fn(*self.args, *args, **self.kwargs, **kwargs)
```

Which can be used like this:

```py
args = Arguments("foo", bar="bar")

# apply arguments to function
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
args(test, "baz", sit="sit")
# prints: ('foo', 'baz') {'bar': 'bar', 'sit': 'sit'}
```

You can enhance this structure to do more advanced argument management: specify exact positional arguments, create partial/partialmethod wrappers, merge Arguments, load from JSON, etc. (I have done so in the past, and perhaps will consider publishing a pip package)

Answer (score 3):

You could keep them in a list of tuple and dict for a relatively idiomatic looking * and ** unpack style:

```py
args_list = [
    (('tas', 'alpha'), {'action': 'pro', 'set': False}),
    (('mas', 'beta'), {'action': 'sub', 'set': True}),
    ...
]

for args, kwargs in args_list:
    t.addelement(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate named and positonal arguments and use asterisk unpacking:

```
args = ("tas", "alpha")
kwargs = {action:"pro", set:False}
t.addelement(*args, **kwargs)
```